# status page empty

Tags: facebook-apps, status

I'm trying to display my Facebook status on my personal website. I tried this great tutorial http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website

The code work great for a couple of Facebook page that I own. But for a specific FB Page I get to step 4 and then get nothing.

{
“data”: [

]
}
Not sure what I’m doing wrong? Any thoughts

The Facebook Page is `http://facebook.com/KINGDOM.Gentlemans.Club`
(remove space after http://)

The Facebook Page_ID is
114357805248420

Example
`https://graph.facebook.com/114357805248420/feed?access_token=???????`

Does someone know why I get a blank data page?

Thank you
Marc

Answer (score 1):

I can't find your page on Facebook (over 21 from the USA), so your problem is one of two things:

1. Your ID and page username are wrong. I should be able to see your page at `facebook.com/USERNAME` or `facebook.com/PAGE_OR_USER_ID`. I can't see it at either of these from the information in your original post.
2. You've got country and/or age restrictions on your page. If that's the case, your generic App access token isn't going to work. To show the feed of a restricted page on a website, Facebook requires you use the access token of a user who has permission to see your page. This prevents your restricted content from being shown to people who shouldn't be looking at it. If you don't have any restrictions on your site, then you don't need an access token to view the results.

BTW, don't **EVER** post real access tokens on SO. Anyone can harvest and use them. You should reset your KingomFeed app access token **NOW**.